# Sorting Python data frame according to dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to sort a python data frame according to dates in the format that can be seen on the image. The output that I want to receive is the same data frame but at index 0 I would have January 2013 and the corresponding amount and at index 1 I would have February 2013 etc.

[image]

Comment: Please include an example of the code that you used to construct the dataframe shown in the image.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Amount':['54241.25','54008.83','54008.82'] ,
    'Date':['05/01/2015','05/01/2017','06/01/2017']})
df['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.sort_values('Date', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert your `Date` column to a datetime, then you can sort the dataframe by that column

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['05-2016', '05-2017', '06-2017', '01-2017', '02-2017'],
                   'Amount': [2,5,6,3,2]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m-%Y')
df = df.sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which gives:

```
        Date  Amount
0 2016-05-01       2
1 2017-01-01       3
2 2017-02-01       2
3 2017-05-01       5
4 2017-06-01       6
```